# Running a normal pull and a sum() in the same SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, union

I'm looking to run the following two queries as a single query and am at a loss with how to do so. This (1 row of DATA1, DATA2, DATA3 per ID):

```
SELECT

ID
DATA1
DATA2
DATA3

FROM TABLE1
```

And this (multiple rows of DATA 4 and DATA5 per ID):

```
SELECT

TABLE1.ID
SUM(TABLE2.DATA4)
SUM(TABLE2.DATA5)

FROM TABLE1

JOIN TABLE2
ON TABLE2.ID = TABLE1.ID

GROUP BY ID;
```

To where the output is a single table (100k~ rows) with the columns: ID, DATA1, DATA2, DATA3, SUM(DATA4), SUM(DATA5).

Is this possible? Tried to use UNION and it says I need the same expressions for each query, which make sense. Intermediate SQL user so I'm not sure what else to throw at it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the extra columns to the `select` and `group by`:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.DATA1, t1.DATA2, t1.DATA3,
       SUM(t2.DATA4), SUM(t2.DATA5)
FROM TABLE1 t1 JOIN
     TABLE2 t2
     ON t2.ID = t1.ID
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.DATA1, t1.DATA2, t1.DATA3;
```

Answer (score 0):

If want the summation grouped only on ID you can perform the summation as a sub-select and join it back into the main query:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.DATA1, t1.DATA2, T1.DATA3, ss.TOT_DATA4, ss.TOT_DATA5
  FROM TABLE1 t1
  INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, SUM(DATA4) AS TOT_DATA4, SUM(DATA5) AS TOT_DATA5
                FROM TABLE1
                GROUP BY ID) ss
    ON ss.ID = t1.ID
```

Done in this manner you'll get the same values to SUM_DATA4 and SUM_DATA5 for each value if ID, regardless of the DATA1, DATA2, and DATA3 values.

Best of luck.